# How to insert blank page without header and footer after every 3rd page in Word document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a Word document of 8000 pages. I would like to insert a blank page after every 3rd page of the document without header and footer. Is there any easy way? Any way to perform this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a macro. Use [Macro Recorder](http://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/) to make a macro. A macro is a piece of software that repeats given keypresses. So you set this tool to consequently make the following keys pressed: ctrl + enter, release ctrl, release enter, press F5, release F5. And you can switch on a function for repeating those keys.

Comment: i am sure that there are shortkeys for inserting header and footer. You can all find them on http://office2010.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-microsoft-word-HP010370109.aspx.

Comment: i am not good in writing macros

Comment: I will help you, just a second and i will make this Macro for you work.

Comment: i am running ms word 2013

Comment: you can make a macro in the tab view. I dont have office, so i cannot test this properly but this should work: press pageDown -> release pageDown -> press pageDown -> release pageDown -> press pageDown -> release pageDown -> press pageDown -> release pageDown -> press pageDown -> release pageDown -> press pageDown -> release pageDown ->press ctrl -> press enter -> release enter -> release ctrl. I dont know the shortcut for editing the header or footer, but if you have that one, you can just add that to this sequence.